# Usage of Java AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

In this course, I am creating an application "News Reader". Basicly, I need to get ID's of the news from an API(First `AsyncTask` call), then using those ID's, I get the data for of every news article(Second Async call), and in that data there is an URL that leads to that article. 
When I get the URL, I store it in a DB and it is used later. 
In the course, it was done with

```
getNews news = new getNews();
String result = news.execute("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty").get();
```

, the `onPostExecute()` was not used, and I want to use it.

So, here is the class that gets the ID's of the articles(First Async Call)

```
public class getNews extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL url;
        String result = "";
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();
            while(data != -1){
                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;
                data = reader.read();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
            //System.out.println("asasd" + jsonArray);
            for(int i = 0; i< 20; i++){


            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the `onPostExecute()`, when looping through the data I got, I have to make an Async call to every ID I get in that data.

So is there any way to do it without creating another class that uses `AsyncTask`?

Comment: Why don't you just do everything in that `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground()`? Nothing says you have to parse the JSON in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Well that was simple.Thank you, sometimes the solutions are so simple I oversee them.

Comment: Sounds like an excellent use case for RxJava

Comment: Yes try with RXJava its simple and useful. https://github.com/saveendhiman/SampleApp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse your data in `doInBackground()` instead of `onPostExecute` method. After you are done with parsing and extracting data from JSON response, call next API and parse its response also in same `doInBackground()` method.

**SIDENOTE**

It is always recommended to keep context separate and don't mix things. Modularity helps when extending your code with additional functionality. There is no harm in creating dedicated `class` which `extends` `AsyncTask`. Keeps the code clean for readibility and understanding later on.